# Viewing columns from an existing table using Flask-admin

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I can display the entire table and edit it in Flask-admin using metadata.tables ['table name']

However, i wish to view only certain columns from the table.

I have no knowledge of Sqlalchemy so could anyone help me out on this?